# GoJS | How is it possible to retrieve the array of the selected nodes?

Tags: gojs

I'm using GoJs [Flow builder](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/flowBuilder.html) and I've been trying to alert the IDs of the selected nodes (the blue ones) when clicking on a button inside the menu (that opens when you right-click on an object):

[image: how to retrieve the array of the selected nodes]

That is, I want it to alert "1,2,3" when clicked "Alert IDs".

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  myDiagram.nodeTemplate.contextMenu =
    $(go.Adornment, "Vertical",
      $("ContextMenuButton",
        $(go.TextBlock, "Alert keys"),
        {
          click: function(e, obj) {
            var msg = "";
            e.diagram.selection.each(function(n) {
              if (!n instanceof go.Node) return;
              if (msg.length > 0) msg += ", ";
              msg += n.data.key;
            })
            alert(msg);
          }
        }
      ),
      $("ContextMenuButton",
      . . .
```

Read more about collections at http://gojs.net/latest/intro/collections.html.

Also, to answer your question more literally:
`myDiagram.selection.toArray()` will return a JavaScript Array of selected Parts, on which you could use Array functions.